# Getting the restore location of an item inside the Recycle Bin, prior to restoring

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

I have a folder named `src` in the Recycle Bin. The context menu gives the option to restore, but it gives no hint about the location where the item would be restored to.

Is there any way to find that location?

It is not acceptable to restore the folder first, and then search it within the file system, because I have many `src` folders.

[image: printscreen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the view to details and you will see the original location. The Properties would also have the folder but not the whole path. In addition you could always drag it out if you just need the files within that folder and move it to the correct location after that.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, simply selecting **"Restore"** will blindly restore the file/directory to where it was. *(Sometimes this is what you want. Sometimes you need to be a little more careful: maybe another directory with the same name has been recreated in the original location; maybe you want to make sure files with the same name are not overwritten; etc.)*

Instead, select **"Cut"**. Navigate to the directory path you want, right-click and select **"Paste"**.